# Why "#facdb13" will become "#d?Æ?"

Tags: java, xml, encode

I have an xml.. there is a value with "#facdb13"

when i marshal and unmarshall it...

the value change to "#d?Æ?"  causing a error.

Comment: I am not even sure I know what the question is. But sounds like you read an non-xml file and got a bunch of garbage errors. I wouldn't think too hard about the error but just make sure the .xml file is not corrupt.

Comment: might want to include some source code...